# Read '*.txt' file from google drive in java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am having some text files in my google drive and wants to read them in my java code. The below code only reads its metadata but not the contents of file.

```
  URL fileURL = new URL("https://doc-0c-ao-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs....");
  Scanner readFile = new Scanner(fileURL.openStream());
  while(readFile.hasNext())
      System.out.println(readFile.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the link you're using a direct (perma)link to the .txt file?
Like this link: [plain text file](http://www.textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt)

Or does the link you're using open in google drive (browser)?

---

EDIT:

Like you said in your commend, the file starts downloading. So the link you're using, is in fact a download link and not a direct link to the .txt file.

You can do two things:

Get the direct link to the .txt file

Or

Use the Google Docs API.

Comment: I'll change my answer (or delete it) once you respond. I can't commend on your question yet with my reputation

Comment: It opens in Google drive(browser). but once i paste that url in browser it downloads that file.

Comment: can you please share some piece of code or any link for that thanks!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples Check the `downloadFile(Drive drive, File file)` method

Comment: Thanks, let me check :)